# My Android app is not showing up when starting an activity with Intent.ACTION_PICK

Tags: android, android-intent

I am developing an Android application that contains a Grid View with images in it. I'd like this application to be able to respond when a user wants to choose an image. I have put the following in the manifest of my application:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I've made another small application and the main function is to start an activity like so:

```
Intent selectImageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
startActivityForResult(selectImageIntent, REQUEST_SELECT_IMAGE);
```

When I click the button that runs the above code, I get a list of applications to choose from. However, my first application is not one of them. I have debugged every which way as well as been all over SO and the Android documentation about Intents and found nothing that would indicate that I've written the intent filter incorrectly in the first application or written the Intent incorrectly in the second application.

Additional Information:
Tested on Emulator - Nexus 5x @ 7.1.1, API 25 - This pulls up Google Drive immediately
Tested on Physical Device - Essential PH-1 @ 8.1.0, API 27 - This gives me multiple applications to choose from but my application is not one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason its not triggered is because you haven't set the `type` correctly. From your "another application" do following:

```
Intent selectImageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
selectImageIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivity(selectImageIntent);
```

Comment: Absolutely right. It's late and I'm losing my mind. So, about par for the course in development, right?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Great! Happens sometimes :-) Enjoy Coding :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the type of `Intent`.As you have mentioned in your `AndroidMenifest.xml` file `"image/*"` then you need to set it before stating your `Intent`.

```
Intent selectImageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
selectImageIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(selectImageIntent, REQUEST_SELECT_IMAGE);
```